# Authorization code grant in lambda AWS with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm developing a lambda service with Serverless Framework that is responsible for logging into Cognito.

```
const aws_cognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const authDetails = new aws_cognito.AuthenticationDetails({
    Username: usuario,
    Password: password
});

const poolData = {
    UserPoolId: XXXXXXXX,
    ClientId: XXXXXXX
};

const userPool = new aws_cognito.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

const userData = {
    Username: usuario,
    Pool: userPool
};

const cognitoUser = new aws_cognito.CognitoUser(userData);

cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
    onSuccess: () => {
        console.log('OK');
    },
    onFailure: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

For business reasons I need to simulate the UI that Cognito generates. The system should support OAUTH flows: "Authorization code grant" and "Implicit grant".

"Implicit grant" works without problems, but I can not obtain the authorization code for "Authorization code grant".
Is there any way to obtain the authorization code with the AWS SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you are able to implement the "Implicit Flow" without using the Hosted UI but you want to know how to implement "Authorization Grant Flow".

> You can use any HTTP client within your Web application to send HTTP
>   requests to Cognito Auth Endpoints to go through the Code grant flow.
>   These are REST API endpoints and also no SDK is required to perform
>   the operation.

Please see the below steps to understand the flow of the process using the API calls:

1) Make a GET request to AUTHORIZATION endpoint to receive the XSRF tokens [1].
You will need to pass the required parameters while making this request. The required parameters are response_type (code or token), client_id and redirect_uri. As per your use-case, since you are using "Authorization Grant Flow", you need the value of response_type to be set to "code". 
Once you make this request, you will receive an XSRF token in the response as a Cookie. This XSRF token will be needed in the next step.

2) Make a POST request to LOGIN endpoint to receive tokens [2].
You need to pass the same required parameters mentioned while making AUTHORIZATION request.
Along with the required parameters, you can pass POST body parameters: CSRF token, username, and password.
Once we make this request, you will be able to receive the Tokens in the response. It also provides a Cookie in the response which you can use later to make a request for refresh tokens.

3) Make a POST request to the TOKEN endpoint to receive refresh tokens[3].
We need to pass the required parameters while making the request. The required request parameters are grant_type and client_id.
Once you make a successful request, you will receive a new set of Tokens in the response.

============

## References:

[1] Authorization Endpoint: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html

[2] Login Endpoint: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html

[3] Token Endpoint: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

Comment: I get CORS errors with this approach. Note: I'm calling the endpoints from localhost.